# Matching a rust Enum with recursive definition using Rc

Tags: rust

The following is my test code.

```
use std::rc::Rc;

enum Node {
    Cons(i32, Rc<Node>),
    Nil,
}

fn main() {
    let list = Rc::new(Node::Cons(1, Rc::new(Node::Nil)));

    match &*list {
        Node::Cons(value, _next) => {
            println!("value: {}", value);
        }
        Node::Nil => {
            println!("nil");
        }
    }
}
```

My question is why do I need to use `&` in the match statement? If I remove the `&` I will get the following compilation error:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of an `Rc`
  --> src/main.rs:11:11
   |
11 |     match *list {
   |           ^^^^^ help: consider borrowing here: `&*list`
12 |         Node::Cons(value, _next) => {
   |                           -----
   |                           |
   |                           data moved here
   |                           move occurs because `_next` has type `Rc<Node>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

I don't understand the error message above. I think since `list` is an Rc pointer, I should dereference `list` to match the `Node` variable. On the other hand, if I remove the recursive definition then in Node (just keeping the `i32`) or use `Box` instead of `Rc` then I am able to match `*list`.

Comment: CS curses and tutorials those days should feature a big warning: traditional lists made of pointers are fun to reason with, mathematically interesting, but globally inept in modern programming. No problem today is efficiently solved with chained lists.

Comment: @DenysSéguret that's overstating the case a bit. While modern architectures are definitely not fond of linked lists, the ability to build them intrusively and the simplicity of their lifecycle can make them very convenient and useful. Even if implementing them definitely doesn't fit safe Rust's model.

Answer (score 2):

First, let's give the easy solution: as you don't need the `next`, you can just not try to get it:

```
match *list {
    Node::Cons(value, _) => {
        println!("value: {}", value);
    }
    Node::Nil => {
        println!("nil");
    }
}
```

This also hints at why your code  doesn't work without `&`: you're requesting the node to be moved into its components, the second one not being `Copy`, which means the node has first to be moved out of its `Rc`.

But you don't normally move a value out of its `Rc`: a `Rc` is supposed to be shared so you can't remove the value without checking first there's no other smart reference to it.

If you really want to remove the node from the `Rc`, you can do

```
if let Ok(node) = Rc::<Node>::try_unwrap(list) {
    match node {
        Node::Cons(value, next) => {
            println!("value: {}", value);
            // you may use next here
        }
        Node::Nil => {
            println!("nil");
        }
    }
}
```

But most often, if you have a `Rc`, what you want is either to look at it (as your code does with the `&`) or try get a mutable reference with `get_mut` which will work only if there's no other reference to it.